# Designing a member area on my site

Tags: users, profiles

I am new to wordpress and I have a website I inherited and I have never even heard of wordpress.

My first mini project is to create a page with my members that can then be linked to a personal page that has information about them.  Is there anything I should look into?

Comment: Probably there a lot of place you can look into. For me I can suggest [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103297/custom-post-type-for-staff-versus-using-wordpress-user-profiles/110622#110622).

Answer (score 0):

If you never heard of WordPress, you can have an overview at the Codex in [Getting Started with WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Getting_Started_with_WordPress) and explore the topics as the need arrives.

G.M's [linked Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/110622/12615) has very nice information for your use-case, and sample code with advanced techniques. Worth bookmarking.

To get really started, learn how to make a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). Understand the [Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) concept. And get a couple of content management plugins like [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/) (to deal with Custom Post Types and Custom Fields) and [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields) (this one has many features not present in CCTM `*`). Backup and security plugins are also a must.

<sup>`*` Like creating fields in the User's profile page and making connections with other post types -case you want to link users and a custom post type.</sup>

Plugin or products [recommendations are off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in this site, as it is a matter of opinion and many plugins come and go. So, it's up to you to research the ones that match your needs. As general rule, check the plugin history, support forums, documentation, frequency of updates, tutorials and reviews.