# Store members in custom taxonomy or native user?

Tags: taxonomy, users, members

I've just started Wordpress-programming a few days ago, but I've been programming php 5-6 years.

I've been writing some code -added custom taxonomies, custom post-types/fields etc. Now I want to be able to store members for a club. There are a lot of plugins out there, but not exactly what I'm looking for. Secondly I don't want to rely on other plugins because you never know when they stop getting supported. Thirdly - I want to learn the basics of WP-programming.

Therefore my question: I want to store members (they should only be able to register at front - and admin should be able to add/edit users backend)

What is the **right approach** to do this? Is it to use Wordpress **native users**? Or should I create a new **taxonomy** called club_users? (or something more explaining for the club)

Comment: The **right approach** is rather subjective. I would encourage you to use the native user system, since it provides you with [a myriad of tools](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/#User_and_Author_Functions) that you'd otherwise have to build from scratch.

Comment: [maybe useful](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103297/custom-post-type-for-staff-versus-using-wordpress-user-profiles/110622#110622)